# Drive a rental car from Tashkent to Almaty

Tags: driving, kazakhstan, kyrgyzstan, uzbekistan

Is it possible to drive a rental car from Tashkent (Uzbekistan) to Almaty (Kazhakstan)? I understand that the route also crosses Kyrgyzstan. Would rental agencies allow crossing these borders? Would they allow pickup in Tashkent and drop off in Almaty? What are the documents that we would require for border formalities?

Comment: As with those questions, it's extremely dependant of the individual agencies

Comment: You'll have to ask directly in the rental agency. IMO there's some chance of being allowed to cross the national borders with a rental car, but in all likelihood they won't let you drop it off in another country.

Comment: I know the countries are entirely different, but when I rented a car in Vienna, they asked if we were going to go to Bratislava. That wasn't in our plans for that trip, but they fully expected it might happen. I don't know (didn't ask) if there were additional charges, but they didn't seem to mind. I would expect that _all_ car rental companies expect that the vehicle _might_ be taken out of country and probably want to know for appropriate extra charges and licensing as necessary.